# Changing WordPress Theme Bootstrap without editing the php

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, css, wordpress-theming

I have done most of my theme customisations by `custom.css`. Except I want to change a Bootstrap component from `col-md-8` to `col-md-12` in the theme php.

Currently I have just edited the necessary php in the theme, but I might lose these changes on a theme update. What is the simplest way to do this? I'm hoping I can do it by CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it via CSS.

You will want to create a [child theme](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/)

I'd also move your CSS to the child theme as well.
From their you can edit the theme file.

Be sure to make sure you manually merge any changes to that file you edited into the child theme when you update the main theme.

Hope this helps.